# Creating PowerPoint Document

Tags: c#, xml, powerpoint, openxml

I am busy recreating a powerpoint with xml. i have added all the neccessary files but when i open the document in powerpoint, it says there is a problem with the content. is there any where where i can see more examples of working like this etc? here is a sample of how i am working with it:

```
 private static void SlideMaster1Xml()
    {
        FileStream slideMaster1stream = new FileStream(slideMaster1FilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        XmlWriter slideMaster1Writer = null;

        try
        {
            XmlWriterSettings contentTypesSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            contentTypesSettings.Indent = true;
            slideMaster1Writer = XmlWriter.Create(slideMaster1stream, contentTypesSettings);

            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("p", "sldMaster", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main");
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns","r",null ,"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "a",null, "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main");

            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("p", "cSld", null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("p", "bg", null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("p", "bgRef", null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("Idx", "1001");

            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("a", "schemeClr", null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("val", "bg1");
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("p", "spTree", null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("p", "nvGrpSpPr", null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("p", "cnvPr", null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString( "name", "" );
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("Id", "1");
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("p", "cNvGrpSpPr", null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("p", "nvPr", null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("p", "grpSpPr", null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("a", "xfrm", null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("a", "off", null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString( "y", "0" );
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("x", "0");
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("a", "ext", null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("cy", "0");
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("cx", "0");
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("a", "chOff",null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString( "y", "0" );
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("x", "0");
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("a", "chExt",null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("cy", "0");
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("cx", "0");
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("p", "sp",null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("p", "nvSpPr",null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("p", "cNvPr",null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString( "name", "Title Placeholder 1" );
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("id", "2");
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("p", "cNvSpPr",null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("a", "spLocks",null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("noGrp", "1");
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("p", "nvPr",null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("p", "ph",null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("type", "title");
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("p", "spPr",null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("a", "xfrm",null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("a", "off",null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString( "y", "274638" );
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("x", "457200");
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("a", "ext",null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("cy", "1143000");
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString( "cx", "8229600" );
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("a", "prstGeom",null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("prst", "rect");

            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("a", "avLst",null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("p", "txBody",null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteStartElement("a", "bodypr",null);
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("anchor", "ctr");
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("rtlCol", "0");
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("bIns", "45720");
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("rIns", "91440");
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("tIns", "45720");
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("lIns", "91440");
            slideMaster1Writer.WriteAttributeString("vert", "horz");
```

I have been through all the code a 100 times but cannot see what is wrong. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you try a really simple-example-pptx? There is also this [free ebook](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2007/08/13/1970.aspx) from microsoft you might want to give a try :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good tool for troubleshooting OOXML generation, is the *Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool* that comes with the [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0). It will validate the generated XML, and display what is wrong. Works for both 2007 and 2010 formats.

Comment: can i ask have you guys seen a powerpoint document being created in c# like this? i just want to see more examples so i can have a better understanding. thanks

Comment: @Artic-M00n Creating the XML manually is very tedious and error-prone. It is much easier to work with templates. See [Eric White's blog](http://ericwhite.com/blog/pptx-generation-expanded/) for more information.